# How to reuse Stateful Widget?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a simple page slider.

This is how page looks like: [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MJ2e.png), and this is how transition looks like: [transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax5sg.png).

I set random color in `initState` of `page widget`.

```
Widget _buildPages() {
    switch (_transitionType) {
      case TransitionType.none:
        return _currentPage;
      case TransitionType.sliding:
        return Stack(
          children: [
            AbsorbPointer(
              absorbing: _slideAnimationController.isAnimating,
              child: _currentPage,
            ),
            AbsorbPointer(
              absorbing: _slideAnimationController.isAnimating,
              child: SlideTransition(
                position: _slideAnimation,
                child: _nextPage,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
    }
  }
```

Initial `_transitionType` is `none`. When I press `next` button it becomes `sliding`. The problem is I can't reuse `_currentPage` widget with the exact state it has (`initState` always is called in spite of the fact I create widget only once and then only reuse it in `_buildPages()`).

Could you please help me?

**Update:** Full code:

```
enum TransitionType {
  none,
  sliding,
}

class PageSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  PageSlider({
    @required this.items,
  });

  final List<String> items;

  @override
  _PageSliderState createState() => _PageSliderState();
}

class _PageSliderState extends State<PageSlider> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _slideAnimationController;
  Animation<Offset> _slideAnimation;
  int _currentIndex;
  TransitionType _transitionType;

  Widget _currentPage;
  Widget _nextPage;

  void _finishPageTransition() {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex++;
      _currentPage = _nextPage;
      _transitionType = TransitionType.none;
      _slideAnimationController.value = 0.0;
    });
  }

  Widget _buildPages() {
    switch (_transitionType) {
      case TransitionType.none:
        return _currentPage;
      case TransitionType.sliding:
        return Stack(
          children: [
            AbsorbPointer(
              absorbing: _slideAnimationController.isAnimating,
              child: _currentPage,
            ),
            AbsorbPointer(
              absorbing: _slideAnimationController.isAnimating,
              child: SlideTransition(
                position: _slideAnimation,
                child: _nextPage,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
    }
  }

  void _goToNextPage() {
    if (_currentIndex < widget.items.length - 1) {
      setState(() {
        _nextPage = PageItem(
          item: widget.items[_currentIndex + 1],
          onNext: _goToNextPage,
        );
        _transitionType = TransitionType.sliding;
        _slideAnimationController.forward(from: 0.0).whenComplete(_finishPageTransition);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _slideAnimationController = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      vsync: this,
    );

    _slideAnimation = Tween<Offset>(
      begin: Offset(1.0, 0.0),
      end: Offset.zero,
    ).animate(_slideAnimationController);

    _currentIndex = 0;
    _currentPage = PageItem(
      item: widget.items[_currentIndex],
      onNext: _goToNextPage,
    );
    _transitionType = TransitionType.none;

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildPages();
  }
}

class PageItem extends StatefulWidget {
  PageItem({
    @required this.item,
    @required this.onNext,
    key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String item;
  final void Function() onNext;

  @override
  _PageItemState createState() => _PageItemState();
}

class _PageItemState extends State<PageItem> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Color _color;

  Color _getColor() {
    return Color.fromRGBO(Random().nextInt(256), Random().nextInt(256), Random().nextInt(256), 1);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _color = _getColor();
    print('init ${widget.item}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: _color,
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: 1,
          ),
        ),
        child: SizedBox.expand(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _color = _getColor();
                  });
                },
                child: Text(
                  widget.item,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 40,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              CupertinoButton(
                color: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
                child: Text('next'),
                onPressed: widget.onNext,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post more code?

Comment: @JehadNasser, Yes, I've added full code

Comment: I couldn't run your code because `PageItem` is missing, anyway, I got that the problem is `initstate` reinitialize your state at each page?

Comment: @JehadNasser Yes. `PageItem` is added now.

Comment: I was able to run, slide pages, also color is changing. I am still not sure if I got your problem, I believe that if you need to isolate the app's Logic from the build/rebuild/mount/unmounte of widgets; then you need to use `BLoC` or at least a Singleton(single-shared object at the app level) to share data/ call functions/ load resources without connecting that to the UI. If you found yourself stuck with this, put  use cases of what you want and what you are getting instead with the current code and mention me. Good luck.

Comment: @JehadNasser I just need to be able to slide pages. I don't want parent widget to know about what happens inside every page and set page's state outside via something like `Streams`, because it seems to me very strange to those things just to slide pages.

Comment: agree totally, no need for any stream. I meant a global object with setter & getter to track(store) current page, next page... kind of a custom controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i'm following with the issue. But, did you try to pass a UniqueKey()/ValueKey() to the _currentPage Widget?

Comment: Why don't you pass the Color as a parameter as well, even if its randomized ? Is never a good idea to create or assign values in a build() method.. cause it can get called very often.

Comment: I simplified example. In my case each page has its own complex state, which should be reused during sliding.